Is it possible to know device ABI in Android build gradle?
I need to avoid running a certain Gradle task if the ABI is not arm64-v8a. However, I also want to allow users to download the app even if their device does not support arm64-v8a. I have added ABI filters in the ndk section.
splits {
    abi {
        isEnable = true
        reset()
        include("arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64")
        isUniversalApk = false
    }
}

I don't want to invoke this task if the ABI is not arm64-v8a.
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
        path = file("src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt")
        version = "3.18.1"
    }
}

Does anyone know if it's possible to check the device's ABI not in runtime?

Do you want to build the native library for ARMv7 and Intel but not for ARM64?

@SevaAlekseyev, I wanna avoid executing externalNativeBuild gradle task if mobile device is not support "arm64-v8a".

When you perform a release build, you build for all devices and supported architectures.  You don't build for one particular device.
